# Computing mean of each variables of a list in R

Tags: r

The following is a function of simulating data from simple linear regression and calculating non-coverage probability of each parameters .

```
simfun <- function(n,b0,b1,sig){
  x <- runif(n)
  y <- b0+b1*x+ rnorm(n,0,sig)
  data <- data.frame(y=y,x=x)
}

noncoverage <- function(n,b0,b1,sig){

      dat <- simfun(n,b0,b1,sig)
      fit <- lm(y~x,data=dat)

      res=summary(fit)
     estim = coefficients(res)[,1]
     se=  coefficients(res)[,2]

     ci1 = estim[1] + qnorm(c(.025,.975))*se[1]
     nc1 = ifelse((ci1[1]<b0 & ci1[2]>b0),0,1)

    ci2 = estim[2] + qnorm(c(.025,.975))*se[2]
    nc2 = ifelse((ci2[1]<b1 & ci2[2]>b1),0,1)
    nc = data.frame(nc1=nc1,nc2=nc2)
}

set.seed(494590)
com=replicate(4,noncoverage(200,1,2,.5))
```

and the output is :

```
> com
, , 1

  nc1 nc2
1 0   0  

, , 2

 nc1 nc2
1 1   0  

, , 3

  nc1 nc2
1 0   0  

, , 4

  nc1 nc2
1 0   0
```

Now I want to compute the mean of nc1 and nc2 , that is ,

mean of nc1 will be mean(c(0,1,0,0)) and mean of nc2 will be mean(c(0,0,0,0)) .

How can I compute the mean by R command ?

Comment: Looks like you have an array instead of a list.  Try `apply(com, c(1,2), FUN=mean)`

Comment: @akrun `> apply(com, c(1,2), FUN=mean)` gives error
`nc1 nc2
1  NA  NA
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(newX[, i], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(newX[, i], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`

Comment: I created this example `com <- array(c(0,0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,0), dim=c(1,2,4), dimnames=list(NULL, paste0('nc', 1:2), NULL))` and it worked on that.  Please show the dput output.  `apply(com , c(1,2), mean)#     nc1 nc2
[1,] 0.25   0` or `apply(com , 1, rowMeans)#
    [,1]
nc1 0.25
nc2 0.00`

Comment: Please add a code snippet for us that creates this "list" so that we can help you better

Comment: @akrun isn't it just `apply(com, 2, mean)`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Yes, that also seems to work.  I didn't test all the options.

Comment: @DavidArenburg `apply(com, 2, mean)` produces error 
`nc1 nc2 
 NA  NA 
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(array(newX[, i], d.call, dn.call), ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(array(newX[, i], d.call, dn.call), ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`

Comment: @RYoda I have edited my post .

Comment: Try `mean(unlist(com[c(TRUE,FALSE)]))` and replace with `c(FALSE, TRUE)`

Comment: Or maybe `colMeans(apply(com, 2, unlist))` or `apply(com, 2, function(x) mean(unlist(x)))`

Comment: Or `colMeans(matrix(unlist(com),4,2))`

Comment: I think the `replicate` step can be used with `simplify=FALSE` so, `com <- replicate(4,noncoverage(200,1,2,.5), simplify=FALSE);colMeans(do.call(rbind, com))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as a solution

```
 colMeans(do.call(rbind, com))
 # nc1  nc2 
 #0.25 0.00
```

Or

```
 library(data.table)
 rbindlist(com)[,lapply(.SD, mean)]
 #    nc1 nc2
 #1: 0.25   0
```

#### data

```
  set.seed(494590)
  com <- replicate(4,noncoverage(200,1,2,.5), simplify=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you may want to simplify the output of the function `noncoverage`, i.e `nc`. If the function is always meant to output a vector of 2 numbers, you could replace:

```
nc = data.frame(nc1=nc1,nc2=nc2)
```

with

```
nc = c(nc1=nc1, nc2=nc2)
```

then `com` becomes:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
nc1    0    1    0    0
nc2    0    0    0    0
```

and `rowMeans` gives the result you want.

Comment: I don't think you checked either the data provided or the comments under the question